# Wortstellung mit Partikelverben

Tags: word-order, separable-verb

Warum stellt man das Präfix **ein** nicht ans Ende?

> Sie tritt **ein** für die aus wirtschaftlichen Ursachen zwingend gewordene Schaffung der europäischen Wirtschaftseinheit, für die Bildung der Vereinigten Staaten von Europa, um damit zur Interessensolidarität der Völker aller Kontinente zu gelangen.

Comment: Das ist Geschmackssache - auch das "ein" am Schluss wäre korrekt...

Comment: Warum doch? Mit welchen Präfixen und wann stimmt das so?

Comment: Ich bin kein Germanist und kann nicht sagen warum. Ich kann nur sagen, dass es auch folgendermaßen richtig wäre: "Sie tritt für die aus wirtschaftlichen Ursachen zwingend gewordene Schaffung der europäischen Witschaftseinheit ein, ..."

Comment: Ähnlich: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/23470/is-putting-an-adverbial-after-the-non-finite-verb-okay (englisch)

Answer (score 2):

Ich nehme an, dass es hier nur wegen der Einfachheit und Verständlichkeit nach vorne gezogen wurde. Zu viel Text zwischen den beiden Teilen eines trennbaren Verbes erschwert nur das Verständnis.

Trotzdem ist es gängiger und natürlicher, das Präfix an das Ende des Satzes zu verschieben. Aber in solchen Fällen ist es doch eben besser, es zu unterlassen.

Dies gilt für ein jedes trennbares Verb:

> Er las ein wunderschönes Buch über die Geschichte einer Prinzessin, die im Märchenwald einen Frosch küsste, der dann zum Prinzen wurde, und sie dann bis ans Ende ihrer Tage glücklich zusammenlebten, vor.
>
> => Er las vor ein wunderschönes Buch ...

Comment: _Er las uns vor ein wunderschönes Buch_ klingt für mich schon recht ungewöhnlich. Ich würde das _vor_ am ehesten nach _Prinzessin_ setzen, sonst nach _Buch_.

Comment: "Las uns vor ein" ist definitiv nicht gebräuchlich und klingt nach sehr "altem" deutsch

Comment: @chirlu Das stimmt schon, dass es mit Sicherheit bessere Stellen für das "vor" gibt. Man kann jedoch auch in OP's Beispiel das "ein" an eine sinnvollere Stelle schieben, muss dann nur den Satz leicht modifizieren. Insofern ist mein Beispiel nicht das beste, weil mein Satz weniger komplex ist — nur lang halt. "Er las uns vor" klingt übrigens nur wegen "uns" schräger. "Er las vor" und "Sie tritt ein" sind auf dem gleichen Level. Wäre geschickter von mir gewesen, das "uns" weggelassen zu haben.

Answer (score 0):

Man **kann**! Auch folgende Satzstellung ist korrektes Deutsch:

`Sie tritt für die aus wirtschaftlichen Ursachen zwingend gewordene Schaffung der europäischen Witschaftseinheit ein, ...`

Comment: Man kann es sogar ans richtige Ende setzen: _Sie tritt für die aus wirtschaftlichen Ursachen zwingend gewordene Schaffung der europäischen Wirtschaftseinheit, für die Bildung der Vereinigten Staaten von Europa, um damit zur Interessensolidarität der Völker aller Kontinente zu gelangen, ein._ Es versteht dann bloß endgültig niemand mehr. Mark Twain nannte das die „parenthesis disease“, ansonsten heißt es auch „Klammersatz“.