# Should all adjectives be placed at the end of the sentence?

Tags: sentence-structure, adjective

Some time ago I wrote a text on one site where people check whether what you've written is correct or not.

I wrote a sentence “Ich bin krank seit einer Woche”, and one person corrected me saying that it should have been like “Ich bin seit einer Woche krank.”

I know that the structure of sentences in German is a little complicated and I at least try to find out some rules but with this one I am so confused especially because I couldn't find anything on the Internet about it.

Could you please tell me why *krank* is at the end? Are all adjectives treated like this and should I always put the adjective at the end?

Comment: I guess you don't find anything about "position of adjective", because what you need to look for is rather "position of all that stuff than can be added to that sentence" (i.e. adverbs, adverbial phrases, modal particles, clauses, ...)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is putting an adverbial after the non-finite verb okay?](http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/23470/is-putting-an-adverbial-after-the-non-finite-verb-okay)

Comment: @chirlu I wouldn't necessarily say it's a duplicate because this question is about the adjective and the one you mentioned is about the verb.

Comment: @Robert: Both are about putting something past the regular end of the sentence, into the _Nachfeld_.

Comment: @chirlu Right, but it may not be obvious to learners that it works the same for verbs and adjectives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your version is correct but uncommon. The version that was suggested to you is a bit more common. There is absolutely no rule that predicative adjectives must be placed at the end of the sentence. The only fixed rule about word ordering is that the finite verb must be second in main clauses, and any separable parts of the verb must be at the very end (followed only by extended infinitives). However, it is typical to have predicative adjectives near the end of a sentence since they typically form part of the *rheme*, the new information of a sentence. (Constrasting with the *theme*, already established information of a sentence.)

For the purpose of emphasis, it can still be moved around pretty much anywhere:

> Die Schule ist *zu* wegen der Baustelle.
>
> *Hoch* sind die Mieten besonders in München.
>
> *Krank* bin ich seit einer Woche.

Comment: You can turn the predicative stuff always around as it's a reflection of the subject –– that's clear. But with your first sentence it could also be the prepositional phrase that's wandering: Er ist gegangen wegen der Baustelle.

Comment: @deponensvogel That’s a very unclear case anyway. With *sein* and a past participle, [arguments can be made that we are only dealing with a predicative adjective](http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/14372). However, that can be adjusted for by saying: ‘Die Schule wurde geschlossen wegen der Baustelle.’ Some may argue that we are dealing with two phrases that are joined by a comma. I really don’t know what I would say on that subject without elaborate thinking …

Comment: What do you mean with ›are joined by a comma‹? But yes, German syntax can get you quite depressed.

Comment: @deponensvogel It’s supposed to read ‘are **to be** joined by a comma.’ Does it make sense now?

Answer (score 1):

If you know German sentence structure a little bit you've probably heard about past participle when building the Perfekt. It's at the end of the sentence all the time.

> Er ist *gegangen*.
>
> Er ist wegen seiner Freundin schon vor mindestens einer Stunde *gegangen*.

›Ist‹ is the so-called auxiliar verb and ›gegangen‹ the past participle (which is  an adjective: all participles are adjectives).

It's the same system with this sentence:

> Er ist *krank*.
>
> Er ist wegen seinem Unfall schon seit mindestens einer Woche *krank*.

›Ist‹ is now a so-called copula and ›krank‹ the predicative adjective (Prädikatsnomen/prädikativ gebrauchtes Adjektiv) or whatever you call that in English.

Concerning syntax these two work the same way. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Thank you so much! Your answer has clarified everything I was confused about! I would never come up with the idea participles work similar to  adjectives... This makes a lot of sense now :)

Comment: You are ignoring the possibility to move parts of the sentence into the _Nachfeld_, which is what happened in the example from the question and is absolutely fine (although uncommon in such a short sentence).

Comment: I’m not even sure if the combination of copula and predicative adjective form a *Verbklammer* in the traditional sense … and *krank sein* is not a typical separable word since it is ‘Ich kann mir nicht leisten, krank zu sein’ (not: *\*krankzusein*).

Comment: The scheme I've drawn here is the normal sentence order, as for example in German it is _normally_ S-V-O. You can vary that but what I've stated is a good rule of thumb.

Comment: @Robert: I find it really inappropriate that you've corrected my grammar. The genitive is the case of indefinite relatedness. He can fill the constituents adjunct and adverbial phrase, however can never be taken by a preposition as this is an act of government not of connection. This is all needless information –– because as you seem interested in language you've surely heard about the primacy of spoken language. And the spoken language doesn't know the genitive after prepositions (especially ›wegen‹). It is of course: ›Er ist wegen _seinem_ Unfall schon seit einer Woche krank.‹

Comment: I don't understand why you complain when you write "correct me if I'm wrong" under your post.

Comment: @deponensvogel: What is your standard of "spoken language"? It is definitely wrong that no one uses the genitive after "wegen" when speaking. Maybe no one you know, but how many of the about 100 million speakers of the German language do you know?

Comment: @Robert: I was referring on my thesis not on my grammar. As a native German speaker I have a good sense for that.

Comment: @celtschk: I know that everywhere on German ground (speaking in language terms) prepositions don't take the genitive. When somebody uses the genitive after ›wegen‹ this is part of a North German dialect. The preposition originated there as a noun with an attributive genitive. It later came onto High German ground where the genitive connection wasn't known anymore and it was used as a normal preposition –– with dative. If you use ›wegen‹ with genitive it's non-standard. Cause today we speak High German. Question: Do you use it when speaking regularly with your friends?

Comment: Actually, yes, I know a bunch of people who do use the genitive after wegen, and this is the correct form. Dative is wrong, even though it's common. I'd rather not comment on your native speaker's "good sense for grammar"...